# Is this possible with Einstein (Use Case below)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, einstein-analytics, einstein

We have a use case:

1. We have a field let say price on external object. We have a Salesforce object that is linked with this external object. This Salesforce object has a stage field that stores 'Won' and 'Lost' values.
2. We want to provide prediction or scoring on the basis of external object records(price field) and related Salesforce records (stage field). (We have huge db for these external records to analyze)
3. The prediction should be in the card form as we have for Lead/Opportunity scoring.

What are possible solutions we can seek for:

1. I know we can use Einstein langauge
   Roadblock:

   > Has only Intent & Sentiment api
   >   Can't use Vision for this use case.
2. Use Einstein discovery. 
   Need insights:

   > Can we retrieve results and show them in Salesforce. As far as i know, it is separate product with separate app. Can we get the insights data through apex or Lightning and display on our custom lightning component.

Thanks for your help.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a read through the [Einstein Discovery documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=bi_edd_wb_native.htm&type=0) as it covers off your query.

The Platform Services are not applicable here as intent, sentiment and vision are not applicable to the problem.

You need to create a story in Einstein Discovery to find any relationship between the data you capture and then deploy that story to the object (again all covered in the documentation). Einstein Prediction Builder may also be useful for you as you can pre-define some scores and it will use this data to check. I cannot say for definite if it can use External Object Data though (whereas with the Discovery Story you would load it into the story dataset).

Once you have the story created, the solution will populate a field in Salesforce to provide a predicted value. You can [trigger this using apex](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=bi_edd_wb_trigger_native.htm&type=0) and it will use the story you have created to predict a value and place it into the correct field. From there you can choose to display the prediction however you want.

Comment: Hi @pbattisson, Thanks for your reply.
1. Yes, you are correct, We can't use Platform services for this particular use case.
2. I have gone through the trailhead & documentation( a bit). I know, we can use it to create stories. However, as per my knowledge, we have to dig into discovered stories. 
As per my question, Can we use these prediction measures through apex/javascript and give some sort of scoring to provide prediction or scoring on the basis of external object records(price field) and related Salesforce records (stage field).
And, yes I will again go through docs to dig further.

Comment: @RajendraSinghNagar the documentation covers this but I have added some additional detail. You will need to create the story and then use an apex trigger to fire off the calls. I have updated to point to the documentation on using the trigger.

Comment: Thanks for your help. 
Einstein Prediction Builder may also be useful for you as you can pre-define some scores and it will use this data to check. -----> This will solve our use case.